# CSS - completely remove spacing between columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box center-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.row > div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I'm also using bootsrap (version 3).

I was able to remove margin between rows, but can't remove margin between columns. Is there a way to force it somehow?
I need all "squares" next to each other without any margins (both between rows and columns).

You can see how it looks here: https://jsfiddle.net/a91zujkj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use `col-` class, make sure to set the `.thumbnail` elements `width` to `100%` and use a `no-padding` class on the `col-` elements.

Here is an example:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.box {
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box center-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You actually do not need to use `col-` classes at all and floats are not needed either. Another way to do this is using `display: inline-block`.

Here is how that looks:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
</div>
```

And if you're really brave you could also use CSS Grid layout. ;)

> [**CSS Grid Layout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
>
> *CSS Grid layout excels at dividing a page into major regions, or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.*

Here is how that goes:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,100px);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.col-*-4` is wider than `100px`, which is the width you've defined for the `.thumbnail` elements.

You can just remove the `.col-*` classes and use `.pull-left` instead.

```css
.box {
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.row > div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box center-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-left` and `padding-right` for `.col` classes and then change `width: 100px;` to `width: 100%;` for `.row > div > div`

```css
.box {
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.padding-0{
    padding-right:0 !important;
    padding-left:0 !important;
}
.row > div > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box center-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
                <div class="thumbnail">A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Row has it's own style and add margin to element, you can remove it by adding :

```
.box >.row{
  margin:0;
}
```